# How do I access individual char's in an array of char pointers?

Tags: c

This is my array of pointers:

```
const char *a[]
```

By doing this:

```
a[i]
```

I can access the strings in the array, but how do I access the individual characters?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same way: `a[i][j]`

Comment: ... supposing that you have actually stored any valid pointers in `a`, which the code presented does not demonstrate.